# Word for Blade within a Blade

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that means "blade within a blade"? It doesn't have to be "blade" specifically, but anything sharp (i.e. "knife within a knife", "dagger within a dagger", "[sharp object] within a [sharp object]").

Not certain if this is a valid geometric phenomenon, but the desire for such a word exists.

I'm also open to wordplay. The word itself doesn't have to formally exist, so long as its meaning is easily understood.

Example sentence:

> The blade of a greatsword is smashed. Within the debris was a smaller dagger; a blade within a blade; a(n) [word I'm looking for].

Comment: Are you asking about an arrangement where the larger knife acts as the sheath, as it were,  for the smaller knife.

Comment: https://www.medievalcollectibles.com/p-46383-carbon-fiber-cane-sword-with-hidden-dagger.aspx

Comment: The cutting version of a turducken?

Comment: [Gerber Gator Combo Axe](https://amzn.to/2AzAmxA)

Comment: Is this a metaphor for something, or do you literally mean a blade enclosed by another blade?

Comment: Not a metaphor. A physical blade, that if broken apart, contains another blade within it.

Comment: Can you give a specific example?

Comment: Yeah, "The blade of a greatsword is smashed. Within the debris was a smaller dagger; a blade within a blade; a(n) [word I'm looking for]".

Answer (score 1):

More generally (not necessarily sharp thing), one thing inside of another is "nested":

> to fit or place one within another: to nest boxes for more compact storage.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nested

You could also use "embedded" or "enclosed".

Comment: Unfortunately I was hoping for some sort of sharp context. Thanks for the suggestion though.